# Date range filter VBA

Tags: vba, excel

How do I make the below filter work? The reports are generated weekly and the user needs to enter just the beginning and end date. The filter must be applied based on he values the user gives.

I recorded a macro and got the code as

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$29663").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    ">=5/14/2018", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=5/18/2018"
```

I want to reference cells in the above sentence instead of values:

Something like below:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$29663").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Value
```

The above statement is throws errors.

The date values are 5/14/2018 and 5/19/2018

Sample values in the field

```
5/1/2018
5/1/2018
5/1/2018
5/1/2018
5/1/2018
5/1/2018
```

(formatted as short date)

Comment: Are you filtering a table or range?

Comment: Table, the other columns were ignored. The filter is being applied on the first row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
with ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C99999")
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:=xlAnd, _
                Criteria1:=">="&format(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value, "mm/dd/yyyy") _
                Criteria2:="<="&format(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")
end with
```

Comment: filters correctly to between, but does not take the dates. My date is in the format mm/dd/yyyy in Range("B3")

Comment: Try the edit above. If this doesn't resolve your issues the edit your question to include sample data and expected results. hint: I am reluctant to retype data from an image.

Comment: It worked. I had to just change the format to m/dd/yyyy