# sending emails through vba but without a loop

Tags: excel, vba, foreach

i'm very new at this so please bear with me. i wrote a code to send outlook emails through an excel macro, when certain dates are close to an expiration (these expirations are related to products).
what I have going on right now is a loop that sends an email concerning each date.
I don't know how to alter my code to send one single email that will group all the products that have an upcoming expiration date (I was also wishing to include a table in the body of my email)

here's my current code

```
Sub datesexcelvba()
  Dim myApp As Outlook.Application, mymail As Outlook.MailItem
  Dim expdateCol As Range
  Dim expdate As Range

  Set expdateCol = Range("B2:B100")
    
    For Each expdate In expdateol
      If expdate <> "" And Date >= expdate - 10 Then
            
          Set myApp = New Outlook.Application
          Set mymail = myApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
          mymail.To = Cells(2, 9).Value
        
          With mymail
            .Subject = "Reminder..."
            .Body = "x expires in y"
            .Send
            
          End With
        
      End If
    Next expdate
        

    Set myApp = Nothing
    Set mymail = Nothing 
End Sub
```

if any of you could help me with this, i would be really grateful

Comment: I'd filter for every cell with it's value (assuming you want to send all the products which expire in the same date). After one Date is processed, add it to a dictionary, so you can check in every iteration if the Date was processed and avoid duplicates. For the table try this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48496434/7558682)

Comment: You really should not have 'Set myApp = New Outlook.Application' inside the loop. That creates a new Outlook instance for every iteration. Moreover, you never Quit any of those  Outlook instances...

Comment: You could use a DATABASE field in a Word ‘letter’ mailmerge, with a macro to drive the process. For more details, see:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/many-to-one-email-merge-using-tables/8bce1798-fbe8-41f9-a121-1996c14dca5d
Or, if your Excel workbook has a worksheet listing the recipients, a DATABASE field in a Word ‘letter’ mailmerge without a macro could be used. For more details, see:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_winother-mso_2010/mail-merge-to-a-word-table-on-a-single-page/4edb4654-27e0-47d2-bd5f-8642e46fa103

Comment: You could start with something like this [Date range filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50498435/date-range-filter-vba) possibly using variables rather than cell values. Search for `Function RangetoHTML` for examples of copying the result to an email.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant

Sub testFilter()

    Dim myApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim mymail As Outlook.MailItem
    
    Set myApp = New Outlook.Application
    
    Dim wB As Workbook
    Dim wS As Worksheet
    
    Dim StartDate As Date
    Dim EndDate As Date
    
    Dim visRange As Range
    Dim strHtml As String

    StartDate = Date
    EndDate = Date + 9
    
    Set wB = ThisWorkbook
    Set wS = Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    'wS.Range("B:B").AutoFilter Field:=1, _
    '  Criteria1:=">=" & CDbl(StartDate), Operator:=xlAnd, _
    '  Criteria2:="<=" & CDbl(EndDate)
    
    wS.Range("B:B").AutoFilter Field:=1, _
      Criteria1:=">=" & StartDate, Operator:=xlAnd, _
      Criteria2:="<=" & EndDate

    Set visRange = wS.Range("B:H").Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            
    Set mymail = myApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With mymail
        .To = Cells(2, 9).Value
        .Subject = "Reminder..."
        strHtml = "<html>" & "<body>" & "x expires in y " & "</body>"
        .HTMLBody = strHtml & RangetoHTML(visRange)
        .Display
    End With
   
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```